# How to validate if a user is the owner of an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my project I have 3 entities **User**, **Project** and **Task**. A user can create a task, but the task will belong to the project not him and a project can have multiple users in it.

```
data class User(
  val userId: String,
)

data class Project(
  val projectId: String,
  val taskIds: List<String>,
  val userIds: List<String>
)

data class Task(
  val taskId: String
)
```

So if the data structure is like this. how can I use **@PreAuthorize** to validate whether the **Task** belongs to the project that the users are in.

```
@PreAuthorize("authentication.principal.userId == #???")
@GetMapping("/task/{taskId}")
public Task getTask(String taskId) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a path variable (or to variables annotated with @RequestBody and @RequestHeader) in a SpEl expression using their name with a `#` sign prepended at the beginning.

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.userId == #taskId")
@GetMapping("/task/{taskId}")
public Task getTask(@PathVariable String taskId) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're interested in checking whether id of the retuned instance of `Task` matches the id of the principle, you need to use `@PostAuthorized` (*it's not doable `@PreAuthorize` because the method need to be executed in order to evaluate the condition, i.e. you need to fetch the object first in order to decide if this user can access it*).

And to refer to the object produced by the method in the SpEl use `returnObject` (don't prepend hash-sign).

```
@PostAuthorize("principal.userId == returnObject.taskId")
@GetMapping("/task/{taskId}")
public Task getTask(@PathVariable String taskId) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so how can I make sure that this task belongs to the project that the user lives in.

Comment: @Patrick You want to check the principles `userId` against the `taskId` in the path - it can be done using `@PreAuthorize` like shown above. If you want to check if the principles `userId` matches the id of the returned object - you need `@PostAuthorize`. So what's your use case, the first, or the second?

Comment: I mean user principal only has userId, but the task doesn't belong to the user directly. it belongs to the project where a user lives in. so in this case how can I check whether a user be able to see this task?

Comment: @Patrick You didn't get my question. *When you say "**this task**", do you mean `Task` instance **returned** by your method?* - If yes, see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but taskId will never equal to the userId right...

Comment: @Patrick Can you please be less vague. What do you mean by saying *"taskId will never equal to the userId"*. They have some kind of different format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250499/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-patrick).

Comment: userId is the identifier of a UserEntity while TaskId is the identifier of a TaskEntity. both are difference object with difference Id. but TaskEntity belongs to the ProjectEntity where a UserEntity lives in. does that make more sense.